# Highcharts angular gauge chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dotnethighcharts, gwt-highcharts

Can we print text across the angular gauge in highcharts representing the level of that value.
For example if we have the gauge speedometer ranging from 0-100 km. i want to give 0-30 a different color and place a text across along its perimeter indicating slow, similarly 30-70 medium  and 70-100 as fast. So that tells us if he's driving slow, medium or fast independent of magnitude.
Thanks.

Comment: I was able to add colors differentiating them, but i want to know if we can add some text across the gauge, if possible how?

Comment: But the text should be placed in colored area or somewhere ? Have you any mockup of that?

Comment: Thanks, i found an alternative way to show the text